# Firebase with c# error in POST

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, win-universal-app

I have installed firesharp and in my cs code, I have

```
                IFirebaseConfig config = new FirebaseConfig
                {
                   BasePath = "myapp.firebaseapp.com/" //actual authDomain
                };

                IFirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient(config);
                PushResponse responseval = await client.PushAsync("registered", 10);
```

In my firebase database I have a node registered that I wanted to add 10, but the above fails and throws an error

```
An eror ocurred while execute request path method POST.
```

In the firebase database, I have also disabled authentication hence anyone can read and write, what could be wrong?

Also in firesharp docs you need a basepath but firebase provides:

```
  var config = {
   apiKey: "",
   authDomain: ",
   databaseURL: "",
   projectId: "",
   storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: ""
 };
```

Where do I get the BasePath? Am building a uwp app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the URL of your Firebase Hosting app:

```
BasePath = "myapp.firebaseapp.com/"
```

You should instead specify the URL of your database:

```
BasePath = "myapp.firebaseio.com/"
```